Geometric Proof for Cycloid Problems
Let a circle $C$ of radius $50$ units be placed initally at point $F$ on the ground which then be rotated by $30$ units, and shift into a new position at point $G$ on the ground. Let this new circle be $C_1$. Let $CR =C_{1}R_{1} =50$ units and $FG = 30$ units.

By what angle is the circle rotated as it shifts its position?

Using $s = r \theta$, plug in $s = 30$, $r = 50$ and obtain $\theta = 0.6 \:\mathrm{rad}$.
However, is there any other method to solve this problem?

{This problem seems to be dealing with cycloids. I am just curious if there is any alternate solution apart from $s= r\theta$}


$H$ is not vertically above the point $G$!! Anyway, the claim that the arc from $F$ to $H$ is equal to the displacement of the center $|CC_1|=|FG|$ is equivalent to the wheel not slipping/sliding. Whether that happens cannot be proven with math alone. Math folks can just assume that, physicists (possibly also automotive engineers) need to check whether there is enough friction.

For just the math, you most likely want to look up cycloids.

Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen, I have made the necessary edits.
